# Jenkins, can't connect to upload plugins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I don't know why but in my windows machine I just installed **jenkins(windows)** and directly I was able to connect to internet and download plugins etc.

But in my macOS machine, I did the same think downloaded **jenkins(mac)** but he told me that I can't connect to internet to download plugins because I have some certificate issue.

If someone knows how to configure that proxy ? according to some forums, i have to import the browser certificate then put in Jenkins, the problem when i go to `firefox->certificate->your certificate` : It's empty !

When I try to go `Jenkins->manage plugins->available` : It is empty, just a update button, so when I click on update button, I have this error:

> A problem occurred while processing the request. Please check our bug
>   tracker to see if a similar problem has already been reported. If it
>   is already reported, please vote and put a comment on it to let us
>   gauge the impact of the problem. If you think this is a new issue,
>   please file a new issue. When you file an issue, make sure to add the
>   entire stack trace, along with the version of Jenkins and relevant
>   plugins. The users list might be also useful in understanding what has
>   happened. Stack trace
>
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>     at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
>   Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>   failed    at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
>   Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at hudson.model.DownloadService.loadJSON(DownloadService.java:167)
>     at hudson.model.UpdateSite.updateDirectlyNow(UpdateSite.java:190)   at
>   hudson.PluginManager.doCheckUpdatesServer(PluginManager.java:1640)    at
>   java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:343)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.interceptor.RequirePOST$Processor.invoke(RequirePOST.java:77)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.invoke(PreInvokeInterceptedFunction.java:26)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:184)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:117)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129)   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$2.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:186)    at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>     at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649)  at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
>     at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:99)   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>     at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>     at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>     at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:524)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy?  At our office, we do not configure a proxy; however, our firewall still rewrites incoming certificates.  We have to add our firewall's certificates to the keystore in the Java used by Jenkins.  I can't easily describe how to get the cert (When asked, our security team knew exactly what I needed; I have successfully pulled it from a browser but I don't recall how and the steps vary across browsers anyway.  Once you have it Java's keytool is relatively straightforward for adding it to your jre's lib\security\cacerts file.

Comment: Okey, thanks for your time